# Where is the subject in a sentence that starts with a prepositional phrase

Tags: syntactic-analysis, subjects, prepositional-phrases, grammatical-roles

Where is the subject in a sentence that starts with a prepositional phrase. For example the preposition phrase beginning with *after* below:

> After breakfast the boys wandered out to the garden.

Is the subject *the boys* only or *After breakfast the boys*, 
and why?

It would be helpful if someone did a tree diagram and explained the function of the prepositional phrase.

Comment: Did the breakfast wander out to the garden?

Comment: This is one of the times a clarity comma would be useful.

Comment: Agree with @miltonaut.  Here is the rule, "Use commas after introductory a) clauses, b) phrases, or c) words that come before the main clause."

Comment: "After breakfast" is functioning as an adverb.  There is only one verb in the sentence for it to modify.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 - But the overriding rule is "When in doubt leave it out".

Comment: @HotLicks Change "the rule" to "a rule".

Comment: @HotLicks "After breakfast" isn't modifying a verb there though.

Comment: @Spencer That comment isn't as helpful as it might seem when you already intuitively know the answer (and, indeed, it shows that the quetion is a good one!). Consider: "The people in the house were angry" - There the subject is *the people in the house*, not *the people*. So the question "Who was angry, the house or the people" is not helpful or informative.

Comment: @araucaria You are incorrect, questions like this give OP a chance to use their own reasoning to get the answer.

Comment: @Araucaria - So what is it modifying???

Comment: @Spencer That would be true if the reasoning wasn't faulty.

Comment: @HotLicks the entire VP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After breakfast the boys wandered out to the garden.

"After breakfast" is a prepositional phrase.  In this case the phrase functions as an adverb.

"The boys wandered out to the garden" is the "meat" of the sentence.  "The boys" is the subject, "wandered" is the verb, "out to the garden" is (depending on your religion) either another prepositional phrase, functioning as the object of the verb, or an adverbial phrase, modifying the verb.

"After breakfast" tells *when* this wandering occurs and hence is modifying "wandered".

(I don't identify the "predicate" here because different religious cults define "predicate" differently.  Some believe that the predicate includes the object while others don't.)

Answer (score 0):

Subject: the boys, predicate: wandered. After breakfast: adverbial modifier of time. Out into the garden: adverbial modifier of place and direction. 'Breakfast'can't possibly be the subject in this sentence since it doesn't denote the doer of the action like "the boys" (who performed the action of wandering out into the garden).